# Обязанности компонентов MVP

Tags: mvp

Добрый день. Помогите разобраться с вопросом. При MVP бизнес-логика отделяется от представления и управляет данными. Значит ли это что Presenter управляет только данными (получение, добавление, обработка и т.д.) или же он также должен обрабатывать события интерфейса (выбор пункта меню, открытие диалоговых окон и т.д.)? Например есть какое-либо приложение, которое работает с базой данных, но в этом приложении также есть функции не имеющие к базе данных никакого отношения: пункт меню "Выход" или "Справка", смена цвета фона и текста, смена текста на кнопке (Например при нажатии на кнопку, текст "Enable" меняется на "Disable"), какие-то функции для украшательства окна, вообщем все то, что никак не связано с моделью. Весь этот функционал нужно реализовывать во View или в Presenter?

Answer (score 1):

В MVP точка входа View. Которая реализует связь с Presenter и Model.
Наглядный [ответ с картинками](http://habrahabr.ru/post/171925/)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Видел это. Собственно поэтому и возник вопрос: "Значит ли это что Presenter управляет только данными (получение, добавление, обработка и т.д.) или же он также должен обрабатывать события интерфейса (выбор пункта меню, открытие диалоговых окон и т.д.)?"